# Rust. How to read files in Windows share from Linux?

Tags: rust, samba

I'm implementing a software that needs to read files from multiple sources.

- Reading from local filesystem works fine in Linux and Windows.
- Reading from ssh works fine with ssh2 crate (https://crates.io/crates/ssh2 ) both from Windows and from Linux.

Problems comes when I need to read something that is on a remote Windows server. When software is running on Windows, I simply use std::fs::File and File::open passing the full path like "\192.168.2.5\myshare\myfile.txt" . Still need to implement security.

How to do the same from Linux? If possible I prefer to not mount filesystems. Also need to set security.

Most of these crates seem inactive or incomplete: https://crates.io/search?q=samba

Has anyone else did something similar? A good crate to suggest maybe?

=== EDIT ===
Since someone has voted to close because to vague. The question is just one:
"How to read files in Windows share from Linux?"

Comment: [gio](https://crates.io/crates/gio) should be able to handle paths like `smb://…` as well as `ssh://…` and local paths completely transparently.

Comment: @Jmb, I'm going to look, thank you!

Comment: I'm use [pavao crate](https://github.com/veeso/pavao). It is a best what I was able to find.